# Files gets uploaded twice from Azure storage. Possible problem with deleting?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

This is an issue regarding Azure Storage and Azure Functions in Microsoft Azure.

I have a container inside a storage, aswell as a timer function. The idea is that whenever someone drops zip files (containing JSON files) into the container, the timer function will upload the content to a database. The timer function checks the storage continously if it contains any zip files. The reason I choose a timer function instead of a blob trigger is that the database can't handle too many queries at the same time in case someone the container recieves a large amount of zip files.

Now, the problem is that, sometimes the function will upload the same file twice to the database, even tho I delete the file in the storage after it has been uploaded. I have no idea why because it seems to me that the files have been removed successfully every time I have tested it.

So far I've tested uploading local files from a console app, which works fine, so it's nothing wrong with the uploading itself.
I've tested running the method **after** I've uploaded all the zips to the storage. This works fine too.
The problem seem to occur when the timer function is running and reading the zip files, while more zip files are added to the storage.

Timer function:

```cs
static ConcurrentQueue<CloudBlockBlob> queue;

[FunctionName("RezippedUploadFunction")]
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    var storage = new Storage();
    var blobs = await storage.GetCloudBlockBlobsAsync("rezipped");

    if (blobs.Count == 0) return;
    queue = new ConcurrentQueue<CloudBlockBlob>(blobs);
    var ctasks = 30;
    var tasks = new Task[ctasks];

    for (var i = 0; i < ctasks; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UploadTaskTest());
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    blobs.ForEach(x => Task.WaitAll(storage.HardDeleteBlobAsync(x.Name, "rezipped")));

    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Upload method:

```cs
static void UploadTaskTest()
{
    var finish = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
    var zip = new Zip();
    var storage = new Storage();
    CloudBlockBlob blob;

    while (queue.TryDequeue(out blob))
    {
        var stream = storage.DownloadBlobAsync(blob.Name, "rezipped");
        Task.WaitAll(stream);
        zip.UploadZip(stream.Result);
        //if (DateTime.Now > finish) break;
    }
}
```

Additional methods:

```cs
public async Task HardDeleteBlobAsync(string name, string container)
{
    await GetContainer(container).GetBlockBlobReference(name).DeleteAsync();
}
```

The expected result is that every file uploaded to the storage should only be read and uploaded once to the database.
The actual result is that sometimes (this varies alot, maybe between 1 in 10-100 files) a file is read and uploaded twice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is more than one instance has been triggered rather than a single instance. But I am not 100% sure

Alternatively, you can use a Event Grid to Trigger the Azure Function. Since Event will contain will have only context, Which may help you to decide, whether to process the file or ignore if it is a bigger size. This solution will be optimal and also reduce cost of running the function (you can switch to consumption rather than app service plan).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I don't think more than one instance has been triggered or it would have said so in the console. 
I might check out Event Grid later, but the thing is I want to process all files regardless of size, I just don't want to upload them twice. It seems that this is more of a bug issue than what kind of method I use to upload with.

Comment: By the way, with the even grid, is there a way to control how many functions that runs at the same time?

Comment: It will create one instance per event (per document)  from the function, which ensures that file is uniquely uploaded the respective location.

Comment: Okay. I need somehow to be able to control how many files that are being uploaded at the same time tho, because it's a small database and it has a limit on how many requests it can handle at the same time.